# ggalluvial - drop some observations in axis

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

I am trying to create an alluvial diagram using the `ggalluvial` package.

My data contains several groups, one of these groups is large compared to the remaining groups and is only of interest in the first 2 of the 4 axis' in the diagram.

The relative size difference between the groups makes it difficult to read small groups that are the key point of interest.

Is it possible to remove the "C" values from the y and z axis?

data to plot:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
data_to_plot <- tibble(
  t = "origin", 
  x = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = 10000, 
             prob = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.7), replace = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(y = case_when(
    x == "A" ~ sample(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), size = n(), 
                      prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3), replace = TRUE),
    x == "B" ~ sample(c("B1", "B2", "B3"), size = n(), 
                      prob = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3), replace = TRUE),
    x == "C" ~ "C")) %>% 
  mutate(z = case_when(
    y == "A1" ~ sample(c("UP", "DOWN", "FORWARD"), size = n(), prob = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1), replace = TRUE),
    y == "A2" ~ sample(c("UP", "DOWN", "FORWARD"), size = n(), prob = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1), replace = TRUE),
    y == "A3" ~ sample(c("UP", "DOWN", "FORWARD"), size = n(), prob = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1), replace = TRUE),
    y == "B1" ~ sample(c("UP", "DOWN", "FORWARD"), size = n(), prob = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1), replace = TRUE),
    y == "B2" ~ sample(c("UP", "DOWN", "FORWARD"), size = n(), prob = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1), replace = TRUE),
    y == "B3" ~ sample(c("UP", "DOWN", "FORWARD"), size = n(), prob = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1), replace = TRUE),
    y == "C" ~ "C")) %>% 
  group_by(t, x, y, z) %>% 
  count()

head(data_to_plot)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   t, x, y, z [6]
  t      x     y     z           n
  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int>
1 origin A     A1    DOWN      160
2 origin A     A1    FORWARD    29
3 origin A     A1    UP        108
4 origin A     A2    DOWN      203
5 origin A     A2    FORWARD    34
6 origin A     A2    UP        170
```

code to create the plot:

```
data_to_plot %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = n, axis1 = t, axis2 = x, axis3 = y, axis4 = z))+
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = z), width = 0.6) +
  geom_stratum(alpha = 0.1, width = 0.6)+
  ggfittext::geom_fit_text(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE, width = 0.6, min.size = 1)+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("start", "x", "y", "z"), expand = c(.05, .05))+
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1")
```

Plot with the (unimportant) "C" values present in axis y and z
[image]

Comment: as C doesn't look important why not just filter it out of `data_to_plot`? Put the starting proportions in accompanying Fig..

Comment: If I can't do what I am asking, I will either do as you suggest or split the plot in two.